# High CPU Usage Windows Phone 8 - SystemManaged Function

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, windows-phone-8

I'm currently using the Store TestKit on my WP8 App.

I have a Pivot. One PivotItem has several Elements, like a TextBox, which is Binded to my ViewModel (MVVM-Pattern). Anyway, when I click on a TextBox, which is quiet down in the UI, the animation isn't fluid.

The error in the Store TestKit is "Low frame rate due to CPU bound animation"
All MY methods are using max. 20% cpu, but this one takes ~80%:

[image: http://www.imgbox.de/users/public/images/5AYadyGRAd.png]

(Systemeigene Funktion = System Managed Funktion

Stichprobe = Sample)

How can I lower the value? Since it's not a function created by me, I can't use a Thread. I've seen this post http://www.expressionblend.com/articles/2012/03/23/wp7-performance-tip-translate-transforms/ . It describes my problem, but doesn't give a solution.

This is what a property in my ViewModel looks like:

```
private string _myval;
public string MyVal
{
    get { return _myval; }
    set
    {
        _myval = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyVal);
    }
}
```

But the property isn't the problem...

Comment: It helps if you actually post the code that has the performance problem.  **Of course the article you linked to actually does provide a solution.**

Comment: Yes, he has a solution, but I don't know how to use his solution in my project (or if his solution would even solve my problem...). As I said, its a system function (see above image), so there's no actual code I'm using. I only have a Pivot with several Elements, which are binded to a property in the ViewModel.

Comment: Have you tried removing `RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyVal);` from the property?  It would sseem like that line should exist outside property.

Comment: Still the same. Even if I completely remove the Binding and define the Textbox like this: <TextBox /> , the UI change (Pivot and all the Elements going up) is still not fluid/smooth... it's "jerky".

Comment: You do have an animation like the author of the article I assume?  I hate to repeat myself but the article's solution seems straight forward.  Using `TranslateTransform` causes the UI update to be done by the GUI and the UI thread dedecated to it.

Comment: No, I don't have an animation like the author. The only thing I do is Focus a TextBox and when it's doing 'LostFocus', the setter of the property is being called. I don't draw anything. I just found this article http://fiercedesign.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/windows-phone-performance-best-practices/ and at the topic 'Redraw Regions' the author says "If we see a lot of flickering then we now something might be wrong."... When I focus a TextBox, there's a lot of flickering! Gonna read his article and hope to read something useful :) ... (<- doesn't mean your help wasn't useful @Ramhound)

Comment: I would try to Invoke the UI update using the `Dispatcher` in a seperate thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help again, but using CacheMode="BitmapCache" is actually doing the trick. The CPU Usage went down... I just have to set the CacheMode on the elements which need it (see authors comment). Never heard of CacheMode before... Gonna have to try it out

Answer (score 1):

Ok wow, great article by this guy:

http://fiercedesign.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/windows-phone-performance-best-practices/

Read the Topic "Redraw Regions"

If the UI is not smooth/fluid, you have to check which elements are being redrawn every time by the UI. You can do this by going to the App.xaml.cs and enable Redraw Regions

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;
```

If an area or element is flickering, something is wrong. Try to add

```
CacheMode="BitmapCache"
```

to your element.

I had a lot of color flickering in my app. The UI redrew i.e. my TextBlocks, even though I didn't change it. All I had to do was to change all the elements (especially the TextBlocks and the Grids) like this:

```
<TextBlock CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
```

The App is now running fluid.